# Can an Ansible inventory include another inventory?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

we have set of files a.yml b.yml c.yml . Hosts are defined in a.yaml b.yaml. can we get the list of hosts in c.yaml?

```
a.yml
servers1:
 hosts:
  a
  b
------
b.yml
servers2:
  hosts:
   c
   d
-------
c.yml
servers:
  children:
    servers1:
    servers2:
----------
```

Answer (score 3):

*Note: your `a` and `b` examples are not valid yaml/inventory files. I fixed the syntax in my below example*

Ansible can use a directory containing multiple inventory files (even mixing static/dynamic ones if needed) as a single source.

My test files structure:

```
.
└── inventories
    └── example
        ├── a.yml
        ├── b.yml
        └── c.yml
```

Files contents (fixed)

**`inventories/example/a.yml`**

```yaml
---
servers1:
  hosts:
    a:
    b:
```

**`inventories/example/b.yml`**

```yaml
---
servers2:
  hosts:
    c:
    d:
```

**`inventories/example/c.yml`**

```yaml
---
servers:
  children:
    servers1:
    servers2:
```

You can test the result using the `ansible-inventory` command:

```
$ ansible-inventory -i inventories/example/ --graph 
@all:
  |--@servers:
  |  |--@servers1:
  |  |  |--a
  |  |  |--b
  |  |--@servers2:
  |  |  |--c
  |  |  |--d
  |--@ungrouped:
```